# How to remove all location permission asked to android users

Tags: permissions, google-play, expo, android-permissions

I am working on a expo app. I posted it on play store however I got my app rejected due to the following image reason.

[image]

I have tried various things like I went to AndroidPermissions and then deleted all the permissions given in the image above and then submitted the update but Google Play Store rejected it. Another thing which I tried was I removed expo-location however the building javascript bundles failed because of absence of expo-location. So I can not delete the expo location. However one strange thing is that before I was trying ads on my app but then I removed the full code related to that. However Google when rejected my update in that email it was written that "Please note that access to location in the background solely for the purpose of ads will be denied." So this was quite suprising because I had removed the ads code. I even deleted the node_modules full package and then reinstall it and then submit the update but Google again said that "Please note that access to location in the background solely for the purpose of ads will be denied." I tried one more vain thing that I made the code such that expo-location will be used when the user clicks on allow to use expo-location. However Google Play Store rejected this update too. It said you can use these permissions only when you require it the most. Actually I also don't need expo-location however the javascript bundles won't get build without expo-location. Actually since this app is in play store and due to the privacy issues I am not sharing the code because there might be claims that i copied my code from stackoverflow however if this issue can't be resolved without sharing the code then okay pls tell me in comments and I will share the code too. Any help will be appreciated.